# PIN not capturing getpid() system call

Tags: c++, c, linux, intel-pin

Using a code example provided in the PIN API titled [strace.cpp](https://svn.mcs.anl.gov/repos/performance/Gwalp/gwalpsite/pin/source/tools/ManualExamples/strace.cpp) on a binary should provide an output file containing all the system calls used, as well as some other information. The binary I use as a test is a simple C binary that contains a `getpid()` system call, which is the 20th system call. The source looks like this:

```
struct {
  unsigned int pid;
  char data [16];
}test;

void foo(){
  printf("In Foo!\n");
  char *p = "hello world";
  test.pid = getpid();
  strcpy(test.data,p);  
}

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

After the PIN tool completes there is an output file in the working directory titled [strace.out](http://www.pastebucket.com/303418), which contains all of the system call information. The file contains about 28 different system calls, but none of them are labeled 20, or the `getpid()` system call. The system call number is the first number following the colon on each line.

Comment: getpid is syscall nr 39 with 64-bit, maybe that's the reason you can't find it?

Comment: @Ctx I am running on a 64-bit machine, so yes that would be it. Thank you.